# Char Array Returning Integers

Tags: string, char

I've been working through this exercise, and my output is not what I expect.

*(Check substrings) You can check whether a string is a substring of another string
by using the indexOf method in the String class. Write your own method for
this function. Write a program that prompts the user to enter two strings, and
checks whether the first string is a substring of the second.*

** My code compromises with the problem's specifications in two ways: it can only display matching substrings to 3 letters, and it cannot work on string literals with less than 4 letters. I mistakenly began writing the program without using the suggested method, indexOf. My program's objective (although it shouldn't entirely deviate from the assignment's objective) is to design a program that determines whether two strings share at least three consecutive letters.

The program's primary error is that it generates numbers instead of char characters. I've run through several, unsuccessful ideas to discover what the logical error is. I first tried to idenfity whether the char characters (which, from my understanding, are underwritten in unicode) were converted to integers, considering that the outputted numbers are also three letters long. Without consulting a reference, I know this isn't true. A comparison between java and javac outputted permutation of 312, and a comparison between abab and ababbab ouputted combinations of 219. j should be > b. My next thought was that the ouputs were indexes of the arrays I used. Once again, this isn't true. A comparison between java and javac would ouput 0, if my reasoning were true.

public class Substring {

```
  public static char [] array;
  public static char [] array2;

  public static void main (String[]args){

    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your two strings here, the longer one preceding the shorter one");
    String container1 = input.next();
    String container2 = input.next();
    char [] placeholder = container1.toCharArray();
    char [] placeholder2 = container2.toCharArray();
    array = placeholder;
    array2 = placeholder2;

    for (int i = 0; i < placeholder2.length; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < placeholder.length; j ++){
        if (array[j] == array2[i]) matcher(j,i);
      }
    }
  }

  public static void matcher(int higher, int lower){
    if ((higher < array.length - 2) && (lower < array2.length - 2))
    if (( array[higher+1] == array2[lower+1]) && (array[higher+2] == array2[lower+2]))
      System.out.println(array[higher] + array[higher+1] + array[higher+2] ); 

  }
}
```

Comment: The `+` operator promotes `short`s, `char`s, and `byte`s to `int`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` operator promotes `short`s, `char`s, and `byte`s operands to `int`s, so

```
array[higher] + array[higher+1] + array[higher+2]
```

has type `int`, not type `char` which means that

```
System.out.println(...)
```

binds to

```
System.out.println(int)
```

which displays its argument as a decimal number, instead of binding to

```
System.out.println(char)
```

which outputs the given character using the `PrintStream`'s encoding.